# Chaining Iterators To Flat Iterator

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator, python-itertools

Trying to solve my problem using chain from itertools. I have a list of iterators and I want to get an iterator that iterates through items of the iterators in the list in a seamless manner. Is there a way to do so? Perhaps another tool instead of chain would be more suitable?

Simplified example of my code:

```
iter1 = iter([1,2])
iter2 = iter([3,4])
iter_list = [iter1, iter2]
chained_iter = chain(iter_list)
```

Desired result:

```
chained_iter.next() --> 1
chained_iter.next() --> 2
chained_iter.next() --> 3
chained_iter.next() --> 4
```

Actual result:

```
chained_iter.next() --> <listiterator at 0x10f374650>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) instead:

```
chained_iter = chain.from_iterable(iter_list)
```

You passed a *single iterable* to `chain()`; it is designed to take the elements from *multiple* iterables and chain those. It doesn't matter that that single iterable contains more iterators.

You could also apply that list using the `*` syntax:

```
chained_iter = chain(*iter_list)
```

That works fine for a list, but if `iter_list` was itself an endless iterator, you probably wouldn't want Python to try to expand that into separate arguments.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> iter1 = iter([1, 2])
>>> iter2 = iter([3, 4])
>>> iter_list = [iter1, iter2]
>>> chained_iter = chain.from_iterable(iter_list)
>>> next(chained_iter)
1
>>> next(chained_iter)
2
>>> next(chained_iter)
3
>>> next(chained_iter)
4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way :

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> iter1 = iter([1,2])
>>> iter2 = iter([3,4])
>>> iter_list = [iter1, iter2]
>>> chained_iter = chain(*iter_list)
>>> next(chained_iter)
1
>>> next(chained_iter)
2
>>> next(chained_iter)
3
>>> next(chained_iter)
4
>>>
```